# Unable to update Mixamo Animation to a Rigged character

Tags: animation, blender, fbx, mixamo

We have Rigged character(.[glb](https://github.com/myinzack/Riggedavatars/blob/main/tshirt_walking.glb)) need to add Mixamo Animations to it.

I uploaded the .glb file into Blender and exported the same from Blender as .fbx file

Then i uploaded .fbx file into Mixamo as new character and added the required animation to it.
Then i downloaded the character as .fbx file.  Still i could not see the updated animations.

Pls suggest using Mixamo how can i add custom animations to my rigged character.

Thanks
vij

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved.

Step 1) Download the avatar as .obj file from Blender instead of .fbx file

Step 2) Upload into mixamo as new character and tick the positions as shown below[image: attachment]

Step 3) Add the required animation and download with updated character as.fbx file